# Safari 17.0: e.metaKey + digit press doesn't fire the digit's "keydown" a "keyup" events

Tags: reactjs, next.js, safari

I work with the Next.js app and listen to the "keydown", "keyup" events on `document`. In Safari (version 17.0), for some reason, when the "metaKey" is pressed, pressing the digits 1-9 doesn't fire neither "keydown", nor "keyup" event (but works with 0). In Chrome it works okay. Maybe somebody knows, why does that happen? The code is the following:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const onKeyDown = (event: globalThis.KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (event.metaKey) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    const onKeyUp = (event: globalThis.KeyboardEvent) => {
        // ...
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
        document.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
    };
}, []);
```